# Difference between queue.await() and queue.awaitAll()

Tags: javascript, queue.js

I'm new to `D3` & `JavaScript`.

I'm trying to understand `queue.js` in that.

I've gone through [this](https://github.com/mbostock/queue) link. But still can't get a clear cut idea about the difference between `queue.await()` and `queue.awaitAll()`.

Can anyone help me with an example(if possible)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation you've linked to:

> If await is used, each result is passed as an additional separate argument; if awaitAll is used, the entire array of results is passed as the second argument to the callback.

So the difference is only in how the arguments are passed to the callback. For example

```
queue()
  .defer(fs.stat, __dirname + "/../Makefile")
  .defer(fs.stat, __dirname + "/../package.json")
  .await(function(error, file1, file2) { console.log(file1, file2); });
```

passes two additional arguments to the callback, while

```
queue()
  .defer(fs.stat, __dirname + "/../Makefile")
  .defer(fs.stat, __dirname + "/../package.json")
  .awaitAll(function(error, files) { console.log(files[0], files[1]); });
```

passes an *array of results* instead.

Comment: This array of results contain files or json objects in the files?

Comment: The result depends on the call. For the examples, it's file stats, i.e. size etc.

Comment: Can you please give me some more specification about it? Can you add code for file1 & file2 & how can I access them in both the methods?

Comment: You can't access the files. This example *stats* the files, i.e. you get a data structure that gives you information about the files. You access those data structures as illustrated in the `console.log` code.

Comment: Ok I'll try it & get back to you.